# Question of the minimal sufficient statistics of beta-distribution

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

> The beta distribution with parameters $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$ has
> density$$f(x|\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1},0<x<1$$
> Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are independently and identically distributed
> from a beta distribution.
>
> - Determine a minimal sufficient statistic (for the family of joint    distributions) if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ very freely
> - Determine a minimal sufficient statistic if $\alpha=2\beta$
> - Determine a minimal sufficient statistic if $\alpha=\beta^2$

The above is the setup of our homework question for the statistical inference course. For (a),

$$\prod f(y_i|\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1}{B^n(\alpha,\beta)}\exp\{(\alpha-1)\sum\log y_i+(\beta-1)\sum\log(1-y_i)\}$$

$$\frac{\prod f(x_i|\alpha,\beta)}{\prod f(y_i|\alpha,\beta)}=\exp\{(\alpha-1)\sum(\log x_i-\log y_i)+(\beta-1)\sum(\log(1-x_i)-\log(1-y_i))\}$$

If $\sum\log x_i=\sum\log y_i, \sum \log(1-x_i)=\sum\log(1-y_i)$, the ratio is constant, therefore by Lehmann-Scheffe theorem, $$\{T_1=\sum\log x_i,T_2=\sum\log(1-x_i)\}$$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $(\alpha,\beta)$.

The above is how I approached this question. I first used the factorization criterion to find the sufficient statistics and prove it is also minimal sufficient. However, coming to the second part, I tried to approach the question the same way:

$$f(x|\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(3\beta)}{\Gamma(2\beta)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{2\beta-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$$

$$=\frac{\Gamma(3\beta)}{\Gamma(2\beta)\Gamma(\beta)}\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\exp\{2\beta\log x+\beta\log (1-x)\}$$

$$=\frac{\Gamma(3\beta)}{\Gamma(2\beta)\Gamma(\beta)}\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\exp\{\beta(2\log x+\log(1-x))\}$$

$$=\frac{\Gamma(3\beta)}{\Gamma(2\beta)\Gamma(\beta)}\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\exp\{\beta\log x^2(1-x)\}$$

$$T(X)=\sum\log x_i^2(1-x_i)=2T_1+T_2$$

However, what I have done so far, in my view, is merely showing that the statistic is sufficient but how to show it is also the minimal sufficient statistic I do not know. I tried to find the answer online and found [This material from Purdue's website](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Ewangxiao/docs/stat528/hw/ak%20hw3.pdf). The question looks exactly the same, and the procedure for the first two questions seem not so different from what I have done. I am perplexed about how come the answer directly jump to that the statistic is also minimal sufficient? Did I miss any theorem? Also does $T(X)=\sum\log x_i^2(1-x_i)=2T_1+T_2$ actually carry with some implications?

*Also, when approaching this question I have a more general and vague question that I want to ask.* It appears that other than making a exponential family in an exponential form, Fisher-Neyman Factorization Theorem is enough to establish the sufficient statistics, an it is usually in the product form: [here is just an example for your reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076160/what-is-the-sufficient-statistic-for-a-beta-distribution) . It always appear that the product can be transformed to summation through exponential and logarithm somehow. But when I studied the concepts in statistics I always struggled to make distinctions between the distribution of a statistic and the joint distribution of a set of random variables. I guess it is because most of the time I am dealing with normal distribution; therefore the summation of x and x-square just naturally appear in the joint distribution and I always thought when we take the product we obtain something connects with mean and variance. But these concepts turn out very confusing when I am dealing with other distributions.

For example, the beta distribution. So far from what I have learnt online, both $\prod x_i$,$\prod (1-x_i)$ and $\sum\log x_n , \sum \log (1-x_n)$ seem both valid. However, when considering them as statistics I feel very hard to understand what we are trying to estimate from these statistics. Also it appear to me they are estimating totally different thing, how come they are both efficient? If they are both efficient there must be a one-to-one correspondence if I am not mistaken. How should I link the concept of sufficient statistics with through estimates I obtained from LME and other estimation techniques?

I hope my question make sense. Thank you so much for your time and patience!

Comment: For showing minimal sufficiency, did you try using the method you used in the first one?

Comment: $\sum\log x_n$ is a bijective function of $\prod x_i$ and so on.  Remember that a statistic is not the same as an estimator: instead, an estimator will usually be calculated from statistics

Comment: @StubbornAtom I tried but I don't know how to put that $\frac{1}{1(1-x)}$outside of the exponential form...

Comment: @Henry I think I can understand what you mean.. that's mainly motivated me to ask the last part of the question ... As I feel I may misunderstand the purpose of having sufficient statistic. I automatically connect this concept with the concept of an estimator

Comment: @StubbornAtom also for the link I provided on Purdue's website, I don't quite get in the last question, he merely showed T1 and T2 are minimal sufficient... then he suddenly jumped to conclude T is a minimal sufficient statistic. I don't quite get what he's doing there unless I missed some important concepts in minimal sufficient statistic

Comment: In the third problem, you can check by factorization that $ T=(\sum \ln X_i,\sum \ln (1-X_i))$ is sufficient for $\beta$. For minimal sufficiency you have to follow the usual method, i.e. show that $f_\beta(\boldsymbol x)/f_\beta(\boldsymbol y)$ is independent of $\beta$ iff $T(\boldsymbol x)=T(\boldsymbol y)$ for $\boldsymbol x\ne \boldsymbol y$. It is not the case that the components $T_1,T_2$ of $T$ are individually sufficient/minimal sufficient.

Comment: In the solution for the second problem, they are using [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=1HQmBKMgDaMC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false) (proposition 2.1) property of exponential family from which it follows that $\sum\log X_i^2(1-X_i)$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\beta$. In this setup, a complete sufficient statistic (if it exists) is usually also minimal sufficient. Similar argument works for the first problem but not for the third problem.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sorry for my late reply. We just covered the complete concept today I think I got your reply for that part. For (c) do you mean we are considering $T=\{T_1,T_2\}$ as a whole instead of individually?

Answer (score 1):

$a)$ We have that $T(\mathbf{X})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(X_i),\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-X_i)\right)$ is sufficient for the family $\{B(\alpha,\beta),\alpha>0,\beta>0\}$ since for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb R^n$, $\alpha>0$, and $\beta>0$,

$$\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{x}\mid\alpha,\beta)
&=\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right]^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{\alpha-1}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)\right)^{\beta-1}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_i)\\\\
&=\underbrace{\exp\left[\left(\alpha-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)+(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]}_{g(T(\mathbf{x})\mid\alpha,\beta)}\underbrace{\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(1)})\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(n)})}_{h(\mathbf{x})}
\end{align*}$$

We also have that $T(\mathbf{X})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(X_i),\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-X_i)\right)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic since for any two possible sample points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{f\left(\mathbf{x}\mid\alpha,\beta\right)}{f\left(\mathbf{y}\mid\alpha,\beta\right)}
&=\frac{\exp\left[\left(\alpha-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)+(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]}{\exp\left[\left(\alpha-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(y_i)+(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-y_i)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]}\\\\
&=\exp\left[\left(\alpha-1\right)\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\log(y_i)\right]+(\beta-1)\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-y_i)\right]\right]
\end{align*}$$

does not depend on $\alpha$ or $\beta$ if and only if $T(\mathbf{x})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i),\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)\right)$ equals $T(\mathbf{y})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(y_i),\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-y_i)\right)$

$b)$ We have that $T(\mathbf{X})=\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(X_i^2(1-X_i)\right)$ is sufficient for the family $\{B(\alpha,\beta),\alpha=2\beta,\beta>0\}$ since for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\beta>0$,

$$\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{x}\mid\alpha=2\beta,\beta)
&=\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(2\beta+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(2\beta\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right]^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{2\beta-1}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)\right)^{\beta-1}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_i)\\\\
&=\exp\left[\left(2\beta-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)+(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(3\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(2\beta\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(1)})\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(n)})\\\\
&=\exp\left[(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(x_i^2(1-x_i)\right)+\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(3\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(2\beta\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(1)})\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(n)})\\\\
&=\underbrace{\exp\left[(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(x_i^2(1-x_i)\right)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(3\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(2\beta\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]}_{g(T(\mathbf{x})\mid\alpha=2\beta,\beta)}\underbrace{\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)\right)\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(1)})\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(n)})}_{h(\mathbf{x})}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

We also have that $T(\mathbf{X})=\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(X_i^2(1-X_i)\right)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic since for any two possible sample points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{f\left(\mathbf{x}\mid\alpha=2\beta,\beta\right)}{f\left(\mathbf{y}\mid\alpha=2\beta,\beta\right)}
&=\frac{\exp\left[\left(\beta-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(x_i^2(1-x_i)\right)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(3\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(2\beta\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)\right)}{\exp\left[\left(\beta-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(y_i^2(1-y_i)\right)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(3\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(2\beta\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(y_i)\right)}\\\\
&=\exp\left[\left(\beta-1\right)\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(x_i^2(1-x_i)\right)-\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(y_i^2(1-y_i)\right)\right]+\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\log(y_i)\right]\right]
\end{align*}$$

does not depend on $\beta$ if and only if $T(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(x_i^2(1-x_i)\right)$ equals $T(\mathbf{y})=\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(y_i^2(1-y_i)\right)$

$c)$ We have that $T(\mathbf{X})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(X_i),\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-X_i)\right)$ is sufficient for the family $\{B(\alpha,\beta),\alpha=\beta^2,\beta>0\}$ since for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\beta>0$,

$$\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{x}\mid\alpha=\beta^2,\beta)
&=\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(\beta^2+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\beta^2\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right]^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{\beta^2-1}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)\right)^{\beta-1}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_i)\\\\
&=\underbrace{\exp\left[\left(\beta^2-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)+(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\beta^2+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\beta^2\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]}_{g(T(\mathbf{x})\mid\alpha=\beta^2,\beta)}\underbrace{\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(1)})\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_{(n)})}_{h(\mathbf{x})}
\end{align*}$$

We also have that $T(\mathbf{X})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(X_i),\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-X_i)\right)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic since for any two possible sample points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{f\left(\mathbf{x}\mid\alpha=\beta^2,\beta\right)}{f\left(\mathbf{y}\mid\alpha=\beta^2,\beta\right)}
&=\frac{\exp\left[\left(\beta^2-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)+(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\beta^2+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\beta^2\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]}{\exp\left[\left(\beta^2-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(y_i)+(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-y_i)+n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\beta^2+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\beta^2\right)\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right]}\\\\
&=\exp\left[\left(\beta^2-1\right)\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\log(y_i)\right]+(\beta-1)\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-y_i)\right]\right]
\end{align*}$$

does not depend on $\beta$ if and only if $T(\mathbf{x})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i),\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-x_i)\right)$ equals $T(\mathbf{y})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(y_i),\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-y_i)\right)$